# How to fetch those records whose due date is 3 more days more from the current date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, where-clause

I am trying to query the records whose due_date(datetime datatype) is 3 more days greater than the current day. i want to send the remainder mails to the people before 3 days of their due date. for that i am writing this query.

```
remind_invoices = Invoice.where("status = ? AND (due_date - 3) == ?", "unpaid", Date.today )
```

similarly i want to send the remainder mails saying your due date is over, (in this case due date is past date.) i want to fetch those records for those if we add 3 days it shoud be equal to current day. in simple words i want to send emails after the 3 days of their due date is over. for this my current query is this.

```
 unpaid_invoices = Invoice.where("status = ? AND (due_date + 3) == ?", "unpaid", Date.today )
```

but these queries are giving errors like

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '2016-12-17')' at line 1: SELECT `invoises`.* FROM `invoises`  WHERE (status = 'unpaid' AND (due_date - 3) == '2016-12-17')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '2016-12-17')' at line 1: SELECT `invoises`.* FROM `invoises`  WHERE (status = 'unpaid' AND (due_date - 3) == '2016-12-17')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do an '-' on date in mysql, I might be wrong on that one though. But it's easiest to let Rails itself handle that with a query like this...

`remind_invoices = Invoice.where(status: 'unpaid').where('due_date <= ?', 3.days.from_now)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's write your query same below lines: 
1, invoices = Invoice.where("status = ? AND due_date = ?", "unpaid", Date.today + 3.days )

2,  unpaid_invoices = Invoice.where("status = ? AND due_date = ?", "unpaid", Date.today - 3.days)